# NodeJs request handling on server side

Tags: node.js, http, request

Hi all Currently My System take multiple request as in queue but when first request take too much time than another requested person have to wait until it's not closed Like FCFS (First come First Serve) algorithm.

Now I want something Like that If 5 Request in queue than Next request has give an error `server is too much busy right now Please try after some time`.

Please let me know any other Technic that can handle request better than these or any other IDEA please share your thoughts May it's Helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I think node js server automatically handle the requests because it used event loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its a good idea to serve only one request at a time. Servers are for handling multiple requests. But if you want to limit requests to 5 you can use use closure variable to achieve the same. e.g. this express router:

```
var noOfActiveReq = 0;

router.get('/handle', function (req, res) {
  if(noOfActiveReq > 5) {
    return next(new Error("server is too much busy right now Please try after some time"));
  }
  noOfActiveReq++;
  db.get(req.query.id, function(err, result){
    noOfActiveReq--;
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```